# Бот на aiogram не видит ответ на чужое сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

у меня вопрос\проблема,
у меня есть бот с командой 'обнять'
Но когда я использую эту команду на ком-то в чате, он ее не видит и игнорирует,  работает только в том случае, если отвечают на сообщение самого бота.
Помогите, что делать? Вот код:

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


API_TOKEN = 'токен'

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
  await message.reply("Привет!\nЯ тестовый бот!\nМеня создали для обнимашек!")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['обнять'], commands_prefix='!?./')
async def hug(message):
  await message.reply(f'@{message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['обнять'], commands_prefix='!?./')
async def hug(message: types.Message):
  await message.reply(f'@{message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.from_user.username}')
```

В первую очередь вы допустили ошибку в создании функции:

```
async def hug(message):
```

Не указав тип параметра с которым в последствии хотели работать:

```
async def hug(message: types.Message):
```

После вы использовали `reply_to_message` собственно для того что бы бот "обнимал" только после того как вы ответите на сообщение бота(логично вроде)

```
await message.reply(f'@{message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}')
```

Работать конечно же это не будет так как вы хотите, решение:

```
await message.reply(f'@{message.from_user.username} обнял @{message.from_user.username}')
```

Вы можете использовать разные имена(я про те, которые в вашем случае будут "обнимать" пользователя), в моем же исправлении юзер обнимает юзера. Исправить на имя бота я думаю вам труда не составит.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо) Сам уже написал)